# Usage of Trans Component of next-translate doesn't work following the example

Tags: reactjs, next.js, i18next

I am experimenting with next.js and using next-translate library to achieve i18n support for my website. The main problem I find is to use  example in my website.

I have this .jsx code:

```
<p>
  <Trans
   i18nKey='common:activity.example'
   components={{
     link: <Link href='/kdajsldj' />,
     a: <a />,
     b: <b className='color--red' />,
     }}
   values={{ count: 42 }}
   />
</p>
```

And in my common.json:

```
"example": "<link><a>The number is <b>{{count}}</b></a></link>",
```

This basically throws me an error I couldn't solve:

```
Error: React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child.
```

Answer (score 1):

**2023 Answer**

The example is stated correctly in the original answer

```
"example": "<0><1>The number is <2>{{count}}</2></1></0>"
```

But the implementation is missing the keys needed for the lib to render the correct components

```
<Trans
  i18nKey="common:example"
  components={[< link key={0} />, <a href="something" key={1} />, <b key={2} />]}
  values={{ count: 42 }}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use numbers instead of HTML tags like so

```
"example": "<0><1>The number is <2>{{count}}</2></1></0>",
```

and than you pass the array where you pass only markup with classes to the corresponding indexes like in the docs

```
<Trans
  i18nKey="common:example"
  components={[< link />, <a href="something" />, <b/>]}
  values={{ count: 42 }}
/>
```

Hope that helps.